# How to edit the existing SQL file in Flyway

Tags: flyway

I am working with flyway Db migration, and I have download flyway zip folder and placed into my local computer.

I have two files in the `sql` folder, i.e `V1__Create_person_table.sql` and `V2__Add_people.sql`.

Flyway info

- Flyway Community Edition 5.2.4 by Boxfuse
- Database: jdbc:h2:file:./foobardb (H2 1.4)

Schema version: << Empty Schema >>

```
+-----------+---------+---------------------+------+--------------+---------+
| Category  | Version | Description         | Type | Installed On | State   |
+-----------+---------+---------------------+------+--------------+---------+
| Versioned | 1       | Create person table | SQL  |              | Pending |
| Versioned | 2       | Add people          | SQL  |              | Pending |
+-----------+---------+---------------------+------+--------------+---------+
```

Flyway migrate

- Flyway Community Edition 5.2.4 by Boxfuse
- Database: jdbc:h2:file:./foobardb (H2 1.4)
- Successfully validated 2 migrations (execution time 00:00.020s)
- Creating Schema History table: "PUBLIC"."flyway_schema_history"
- Current version of schema "PUBLIC": << Empty Schema >>
- Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1 - Create person table
- Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 2 - Add people
- Successfully applied 2 migrations to schema "PUBLIC" (execution time 00:00.092s)

Flyway info

- Flyway Community Edition 5.2.4 by Boxfuse
- Database: jdbc:h2:file:./foobardb (H2 1.4)

Schema version: 2

```
+-----------+---------+---------------------+------+---------------------+---------+
| Category  | Version | Description         | Type | Installed On        | State   |
+-----------+---------+---------------------+------+---------------------+---------+
| Versioned | 1       | Create person table | SQL  | 2019-08-19 12:12:40 | Success |
| Versioned | 2       | Add people          | SQL  | 2019-08-19 12:12:40 | Success |
+-----------+---------+---------------------+------+---------------------+---------+
```

Now, here the question is: if I want to update or edit somehing in above two sql files, how can I do that, should I edit existing file version 1, version 2 and 
save the file and run all the above command again?

Comment: [Repeatable Migrations](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#repeatable-migrations) are (re-)applied every time their checksum changes ex: `R__Add_new_table.sql`.

Answer (score 3):

You should not edit your existed scripts. I have to add a new one e.g. *V3__Update_person_table.sql* and correctly update it.

**P.S.**

In the big project, we have tens of scripts that iteratively modify the empty database to achieve a current status.

After that, usually, when moving to the next release version, we merge all existed scripts into one or two (when we do not need to keep history anymore).

**Notes**

This is correct. We do not change existed scripts (this is part of CI/CD). All changes should be added additionally with new scripts. Flyway accepts a directory with all scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i have created new file with version of V3 (Add_People), i ran the flyway info cmd - to check the status, now the status of the sql file.

Comment: Versioned | 3       | Add people          | SQL  |         | Pending. Now i had another question correct me if i'm wrong, As you said, if there is any changes in previous executed file, we have to create new file with latest version, in real time project how we can integrate all the files and how to i deploy in Test Environment.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik, after the release, do You mean, merging incremental scripts that were migrated with flyway?

Comment: @oleg.cherednik, I mean this sounds reasonable only if You clean up history table, right?

Comment: Yes. In this case you gave to clean scheme table. But if time for apply all scripts is not problem for you’r project, then leave all of them